# Dynamically fetch a "since" Timestamp in the body of my web activity and dynamically update it after successful pipeline runs

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have been stuck with this issue - I have a pipeline - see attached a screenshot, that would would download tables from a REST API asynchronously. The pipeline has the below workflow:

Step 1: web activity to get access_token using a POST method. Here, API KEY was passed for the activity to return an acess_token

Step 2: Another web activity that would accept that access_token from step one using a POST method of API calls. Here, the body of the web activity contains this json - {"format":"jsonl","since":"2023-03-07T20:01:39.135Z"}

Step 3: An Until activity which contains another 'web activity' and a 'wait' condition. The web activity in step 2, would get a update query and the one inside the Until activity, would return the status (either waiting or complete). The 'Wait condition' tells the Until asctivity to either continue to the next task when the status is complete or wait until it is complete.

Step 4: Another web activity which will get url downloads that would be passed to a copy activity

Step 5: ForEach activity which contain a copy activity. This copy activity uses the web activity from step 4 to download a files from the api into a datalake.

Following the above workflow, I was able to get the pipeline working and some files were downloaded in my gen2 datalake.

Here is my challenge:

Because I would want to query this data almost on a daily, I want to be able to DYNAMICALLY reference the json in the body of the web activity in STEP 2.

For clarity, what I mean is, say I run this pipeline today, according to the body of the web acivity in STEP 2, I want to fetch file updates "since":"2023-03-07T20:01:39.135Z" to "2023-03-10T20:01:39.135Z". That would mean that, if I run the pipeline tomorrow, I would want to fetch files "since":"2023-03-11T20:01:39.135Z". What I want to achieve is the ability to dynamically fetch this without having to do manually update the json in the body of web activity in step 2. I want the body in STEP 2 to dynamically update to the new "since":"Timestamp" everytime the pipeline is run.

I would appreciate if any  one has any idea on how to execute this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjpOp.png)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, documents state that there is no such case. The output of earlier activities would serve as the current activity's input. The same can be used to specifically put in a variable for future use.

You can only view or copy inputs of an activity from pipeline run output or errors.

[image]

**for your requirement the workaround would be as follow:**

- you have to create a blob storage and upload a file in it with since value.
  [image]
- Then in pipeline take a lookup activity to get since value from file as below
  [image]
- Then pass the output of the lookup to web activity body like `{"format":"jsonl","since":"@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.since}"}`
  [image]
  [image]
- After this take a set variable to update the timestamp with expression `@adddays(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.since,1)` **this expression will add 1 day to timestamp**
  [image]
- Then update this value in blob storage using copy activity in source of the copy activity add the same file as dataset and create additional column as **since1** with value `@variable('output')` for sink also take same file.
  [image]
  go to mapping >> import mapping >> map since1 to since and delete other mappings.
  [image]

**This will dynamically take updated value from blob file.**